# MATLAB GUI "forgets" objects after modifying handles structure

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a load button in my gui toolbar. When I click it, it allows me to select a file from a dialog. I open a .mat file that has an object in it named `sys`.

Once I select the file, the callback is supposed to run the following code:

```
handles.sys = sys;
%% A bunch of other stuff to populate values from sys into the gui text fields %%
```

For the rest of the code in this callback I can call handles.sys and see that everything is there. However, when I exit this function, handles.sys does not equal sys anymore. It seems that the gui has "forgotten" or clobbered the handles.sys object.

Why does this happen and what is the right way to do this? Do I need to reconstruct my entire sys object with a constructor then call `handles.sys = newsys`? Is it happening because the sys object only existed within the temporary `openfile_Callback` function's workspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update a `struct` (such as `handles`), these changes are to a local copy and therefore are not seen by other functions. You need to store `handles` back within the `guidata` of the figure for changes to persist. The first input to `guidata` should be the handle to the figure (I have used `handles.fig` as an example). After doing this, the updated `handles` struct will be automatically passed around your GUI.

```
handles.sys = sys;

% "Save" the updated handles struct in the figure
guidata(handles.fig, handles)
```

Comment: I had to use `guidata(handles.figure1, handles);` because that is what matlab creates by default.

Comment: @toshiomagic Right. As I said, I just used `handles.fig` as an example. It will be different for everyone.